# Creating a form that updates when 'Next' button is clicked. (c#)

Tags: c#, forms, user-interface, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to create a form in visual studio that takes in personal information from a user.
Currently it takes in the first name, last name and birthdate. And I have a 'Next' button on there as well.

What I want to do is, when the 'Next' button is clicked, I want the form to have new options for user input. In my case, I want the form to have new fields for address, zip-code and phone number. As you can see I am describing a typical form you encounter on a regular basis. I just don't know how to implement it. How should I go about implementing it?

Comment: what you are asking for is quite simple there are two ways to do this.
`1` you can add or create a entirely new custom form and then instantiate it or 
`2` you can use the existing form with hidden fields and when calling it in it's creating stage, make those fields visible.

Comment: @Sumo Track - What have you tried so far?

Comment: @DJ #1 sounds good. But at first i though you could have layouts in the form so when Next is clicked it moves on to the next layout.

Comment: @Mike C well, Honestly I had no idea how to implement it. I am new to C# and visual studio.

Comment: Also one more question, If i create multiple forms, wouldn't it open the new form in a new window instead of updating the existing one?

Comment: you could use the layout scenario in your case by using Tab Control and placing Panels to simulate a form there are lots of options also being new to C# that's cool but you are not new to doing a google search are you..? there are tons of examples on the web also check the `Related Links` to the right lower side of this page under the `CAREERS 2.0` section

Comment: you can show the same form based on a button click what you want to do is `make Visible` the controls you want to show in the Button Click event..

Comment: @SumoTrack I understand, however StackOverflow is meant more for specific programming issues that have a specific answer.  Yours is more open-ended, and is too generic to have a right answer.  You can find many resources on implementing UI in C# on all platforms using a simple Google search.  You'll want to return to SO with a question more like, "I am building a WPF application using C#, and I am receiving this error when trying to compile.  Here is some sample code, what might I be doing wrong?"

Comment: @DJ KRAZE I have decided to go with tabbed design. I will do a thorough Google search on it. Thank you.

Comment: @Mike C I will try to have more specific questions in the future. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your form design, make the base layer a TabControl and then create tabs for each "page".  Ensure that your button is not on a tab page, but on the base form.  Then, handle the button click, switching tabs to a new "page" each time.  Keep track of the current page using a member variable of type `int`.

Since you've not provided code, I'll make some assumptions for example's sake.  The TabControl is named "tabControl", and it has n number of pages named "tabPage_Page0" through "tabPage_Pagen".  The Next button's click handler would go something like this:

```
private void NextButton_Click (Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    switch (_currentIndex)
    {
        case 0:
            tabControl.SelectTab(tabPage_Page1);
            break;
        case 1:
            tabControl.SelectTab(tabPage_Page2);
            break;
        case n:  //whatever that last number really is
            tabControl.SelectTab(tabPage_Page0);  //wrap back to the first page?  or exit?
            _currentIndex = 0;
            return;
    }

    _currentIndex++;
}
```

We use something similar quite a bit.  However, we have gone further and created a class inheriting from TabControl that provides a HideTabs member that we use to override DisplayRectangle() and force the tabs invisible.  Makes a nice clean presentation.

Comment: The tabbed design sounds amazing. Definitely going with it. Thank you very much.